# How to return the number of unique observations in each group of a data frame

Tags: r, count, summarize

I have a data frame similar to this:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  Location = rep(letters[1:10], each = 20),
  ID = rep(1:40, each = 5)
)
```

I want to return a table that contains each unique `Location` in one column and a count of the number of unique `ID`s in each `Location` in another column, so it will look like this:

```r
Location   Count
   a         4
   b         4
   ...      ...
```

Note: in my actual data set there are different numbers of `ID`s in each `Location`, and there are other variables in other columns.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Jaap it is closed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct` on the 'ID' column after grouping by 'Location'.  In the example, it is all 4

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(Location) %>%
    summarise(Count = n_distinct(ID))
```

If we need to add a new column, use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

---

With `data.table`, this can be done with `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(Count = uniqueN(ID)), Location]
```

Answer (score 1):

The table class of objects has a `as.data.frame` method:

```
as.data.frame(table(data$Location))
   Var1 Freq
1     a   20
2     b   20
3     c   20
4     d   20
5     e   20
6     f   20
7     g   20
8     h   20
9     i   20
10    j   20
```